# What is the descriptive word or image for something really small, really detailed?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of something like "hairpin" or "miniature": this hairpin/miniature piece of knowledge is only useful when someone is choking on a black, titanium ball-pen while sitting on their head.

Comment: Maybe you'd like ***trivia***.  *This bit of trivia is only useful when...*

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking of *minutia* or (more likely) *minutiae*. These days though this suggests something inconsequential as well as small, which may not be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try **minute** or **minutiae** to be more precise.

**minutiae**

> *noun*
> the small, precise, or trivial details of something.

If you're looking for an adjective to describe something really small and detailed, well you could use **minute** or **intricate**.

[**minute**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/minute)

> *noun*
>
> attentive to or concerned with even the smallest details:

**intricate**

> *noun*
>
> very complicated or detailed

Answer (score 0):

Is [itty-bitty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/itty-bitty) (aka itsy-bitsy) the figurative expression you're looking for?

**itty-bitty**: extremely small, tiny

Answer (score 0):

Particularly relating to knowledge or information, you could use **[nugget](http://tfd.com/nugget)**:

> anything small but of great value or significance: nuggets of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'minuscule'?

*adjective*

extremely small; tiny.

*Synonyms*

minute, microscopic, nanoscopic, micro, miniature, infinitesimal